# Hadoop location in Eclipse (Error: null)

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I've downloaded hadoop from Yahoo tutorial, started linux VM with hadoop and in eclipse created new DFS location (entered IP of my VM, Map/Reduce master port 9001, DFS port 9000.
But in the node I got the error "Error:null."

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Eclipse Europe 3.3.1 and Hadoop 0.18.0.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: There is a newer version of Hadoop plugin at at https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-eclipse-plugin/downloads/list

Comment: Try to set up hadoop on your local instead of using a VM. That way you will be able to configure eclipse easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've configured properly eclipse when had installed it in my VM where hadoop was. But due to **incompatible new versions of eclipse and eclipse hadoop plugin** I refused to use it, because seems to me that using this plugin doesn't have any good benefits.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the additional properties that you are able to configure. I was also getting this problem but the actual problem was that hadoop.job.ugi property was not available to be setup.To fix this, go to "**\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.apache.hadoop.eclipse\locations**". Here open the XML file and just add the property "**hadoop.job.ugi**" with value "**hadoop-user,ABC**" and then restart your eclipse. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, i thinks the problem because there is no folder or files in the HDFS,i solved with these steps:

- hadoop dfs -mkdir /name of folder
- hadoop fs -ls /