# Not able to run Hadoop from eclipse saying Hadoop location in eclipse(Error:NULL)

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hadoop-plugins

I have downloaded Hadoop VM from Yahoo site and started Hadoop VM through VMware player. I saw no issues.
As been mentioned in Yahoo, I made use of Eclipse Europa (v 3.3.1) and I downloaded a jar file (hadoop-0.18.3-eclipse-plugin) to make MapReduce plugin on in eclipse.
I started linux VM with hadoop and in eclipse created new DFS location (entered IP of my VM, Map/Reduce master port 9001, DFS port 9000. But in the node I got the error "Error:null."

[image: screenshot for reference]

What I'm doing wrong? Also while configuring Hadoop variables in eclipse, i am not seeing  in advanced tab while setting up hadoop location.

I'm using Eclipse Europe 3.3.1 and Hadoop 0.18.0.

Did i went wrong in choosing the version of the plugin?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Spawn the Eclipse from within Cygwin to resolve this issue.

Go to eclipse installed folder in Cygwin and invoke eclipse.exe

Answer (score 0):

Above answer helped me;
What he says is after installing cygwin
open cygwin terminal and go to "cygdrive" ( use cd .. and pwd )
go to your drive and look for eclipse.exe
then "run eclipse"

now it will show folders instead of "error:null"

Answer (score 0):

What I did and worked for me was:
following the instructions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190903/hadoop-location-in-eclipse-error-null/):
edit this file: \workspace.metadata.plugins\org.apache.hadoop.eclipse\locations
and add a property: "hadoop.job.ugi" with value "hadoop-user,ABC"

but also modify the property " mapred.system.dir" to "/hadoop/mapred/system". As you can see in [this webpage](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html#vmware-install). I followed all this page for the rest of the configuration.